# getting null value in function variable that assign in ajax success function in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

```js
    function getData(url) {
        var responseData = null;
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: url,
          crossDomain: true,
          async: false,          
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function (result) {
            responseData = result;
          }
        });   
         console.log(responseData); 
         return responseData;
      }    
     var  getapidata= getData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
        console.log('getapidata',getapidata);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: This is not how callbacks work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: You're not waiting for the call to be completed before you assign your `getapidata` variable

Answer (score 1):

It's an `async` event, So you should do something similar this syntaxe may help:

```js
function getData(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp"
  });
}


var getapidata = getData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(value => {
  console.log(value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want to write $.ajax syntax every time when you need to send ajax call. if so then this code can help you.

> **Note** You should must learn how JavaScript asynchronously works because the which you have written will never work.

Here is my code in which i have add some more functionality.
1) dynamically set URL and Methods 
2) Now you can `GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE` using `getData()` function

`getData()` function required two parameter and one optional parameter depending upon you need to send data on server or not.

`getData(URL, Method, Data if there)`

```js
$(document).ready(async () => {
    function getData(url, method, data = {}) {
    return $.ajax({
      method,
      url,
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    });
 }
 // getData(URL, Method, Data)

 //  await getData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', 'PATCH', {title: "new post"})
 //  await getData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', 'DELETE')
 //  await getData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', 'POST', {
 //  userId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
 //  title: "New Post", 
 //  body: "This is my new post"
 // })

 var getapidata = await getData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', 'GET')
 console.log(getapidata)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Thank you**